# Prevent Chrome from loading mobile sites on Windows 10 tablet

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-10

I have an 8-inch windows 10 tablet (Chuwi hi8). Whenever I visit websites with Chrome, it loads tablet version of websites (same is with Firefox too). But I need to see the normal desktop version of the website. Is there any way to force Chrome to load desktop version of websites?

Comment: Sometimes... If the site provides a "show desktop version" link, you can. Otherwise the site takes your screen width and presents a version dedicated to mobile devices. Can you provide the actual URL, I can advise better when I can see the site?

Comment: example url: www.cheapwindowstabs.com there is no desktop version link. I wonder how can I force a site to show me the full site?

Comment: What you are seeing **IS** the desktop version of the site.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have provided it is **not** possible to view the desktop version on a mobile device.

---

The reason for that is because that particular website uses [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) and dynamically reorganises the layout based on the screen width of the viewing device. You can test this by using a desktop browser and manually shrinking the window and noting how the elements are resizes and adapted for smaller view ports.

[image: Example of a RWD website in a desktop browser]

There are a few websites that subscribe to a different philosophy and maintain a different site specifically for mobiles. In these cases the site will provide a link (normally in the footer) to swap between the versions.

The [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.co.uk/) site is a good example of a large site maintaining two dedicated code bases for different devices. From the desktop version I can view the mobile version and on the mobile I can select to view the desktop version.

[image: Screenshot of the Ars Technica footer]

There are several reasons for making this sort of decision but it mainly comes down to the size of the development team and the number of sites they have to maintain. I can expand upon this if required.

Comment: My tab has dual OS with android 4.4. When I browse this site with Chrome on android, it shows the full desktop site. If Chrome on android can why not chrome on windows 10?

Comment: Potentially they have a custom plugin on their WordPress site that is doing something funky with the UserAgent string. That isn't something that is publicly exposed. Without a Win10 tablet myself there isn't much else I can investigate.

Comment: Alternatively it might be screen resolution and orientation. My Nexus 7 shows the "full" site in landscape. Perhaps you could [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1051523/edit) your question with some screenshots?